# if else in for loop over array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm sure this is simple, but can someone please tell me why my code won't run the if statement in this for loop? I'm trying to solve this and would appreciate a hint on where i'm going wrong rather than the answer. I'm trying to find the appropriate element index where `num` would fit in a sorted array so in this case the function should return 3.

```
function where(arr, num) {
    // Find my place in this sorted array.
    arr.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i]<num){
         return arr[i]
       }
    }
}

where([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35);
```

Comment: What makes you think it does not run the `if` statement? Do you get `undefined`? Hint: Look at `var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++`. When exactly is `i > arr.length` true?

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't the if statement, it's your for loop. You're defining it as:

```
 for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++)
```

Which only runs while `i` is greater than the array length, which is never.

Swap your comparative and you're golden.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. See John's answer for more info on returning the index and not the value.

Answer (score 2):

return the index not the value

```
return i
```

`return arr[i]` will return the value at your index like aka 40 instead of 3

also change your logic in the for loop to be < not > since i will not ever be greater than the array length

all together that would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]<num){
        return i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle for your solution [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/as541986/6ano5xjb/1/)

```
function where(arr, num) {
// Find my place in this sorted array.
    arr.sort();
    //changed for loop
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //changed comparison
        if(arr[i]>num){
           return i}
        }
   }
  alert(where([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you find the appropriate place, you’re returning the value currently at that place rather than the index itself. Replace `return arr[i]` with just `return i`.

Answer (score 0):

You tested `i > arr.length` in your `for` loop condition. Given that `i` starts at `0`, it's not going to be larger than any array, so the loop never runs.

Answer (score 0):

Should be more like:

```
function where(arr, num){
  var a = arr.slice();
  a.push(num); a.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  if(a.indexOf){
    return a.indexOf(num);
  }
  else{
    for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
      if(a[i] === num){
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(where([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be loop from the last to first, code below will return 2 is index of 30

```
function where(arr, num) {
    // Find my place in this sorted array.
    arr.sort();
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       if(arr[i]<num){
         return i
       }
    }
}

where([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here!!
I made some changes and it work!:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function where(arr, num){
        // Find my place in this sorted array.
        arr.sort();
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ // Here was another error, the condition was wrong: "i" must be lower than arr.length.
           if(num < arr[i]){ // I change this, because you wanna analyze if the number you pass to the function is lower than the element of the array (It was backwards in the original code)
             return 'The position is ' + [i]; //Shows the position the number should be. In this case, 3 like you say before :).
             break
        }
    }
}

console.log(where([10, 20, 30, 40, 50], 35));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you.